# Object not found when conducting bootstrapping using mediation package to analyze multiple mediators (no error if bootstrapping was not used)

Tags: imputation, r-mice, mediator

I'm using the `mediation` package in r to analyze the mediating role of 5 mediators between 1 predictor and 1 outcome variable. All variables are continuous. When `boot=FALSE`, **the coding below worked**. However, when `boot=TRUE`, **I got the error message below**.

```
olsols <- mediations(datasets, treatment, mediators, outcome, families=c("gaussian","gaussian"), 
                         interaction=FALSE, conf.level=.90, sims=1000, boot=TRUE, boot.ci.type="bca")
    
Error in stats::model.frame(formula = f1, data = list(IRQ_original_total_mi = c(79,  : 
      object 'f1' not found
```

Before using the `mediations` function, I did multiple imputations using `mice` package to handle the missing data.

I've tried to look for similar problems reported by previous researchers, but I'm afraid I can only find one relevant post (see the link below). However, there weren't any response to that post so I decided to create a new post here.

Can anyone please advise how can I solve the error?

https://github.com/kosukeimai/mediation/issues/32

Here is part of the dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11rv1iniNjw6RpgqnYHdhD3FLy_hZbKNi/view?usp=sharing

Here are the codes I used:

```
    ## create a dataframe for the multiple imputation ====
    alldata4 <- alldata3[ ,c('ECR_1', 'ECR_2', 'ECR_3', 'ECR_4', 'ECR_5', 'ECR_6',
                             'ECR_7', 'ECR_8', 'ECR_9', 'ECR_10', 'ECR_11', 'ECR_12',  
                             'ECR_13', 'ECR_14', 'ECR_15', 'ECR_16', 'ECR_17', 'ECR_18', 
                             'ECR_19', 'ECR_20', 'ECR_21', 'ECR_22', 'ECR_23', 'ECR_24', 
                             'ECR_25', 'ECR_26', 'ECR_27', 'ECR_28', 'ECR_29', 'ECR_30', 
                             'ECR_31', 'ECR_32', 'ECR_33', 'ECR_34', 'ECR_35', 'ECR_36', 
                             'IRQ_1', 'IRQ_2', 'IRQ_3', 'IRQ_4', 'IRQ_5', 'IRQ_6', 
                             'IRQ_7', 'IRQ_8', 'IRQ_9', 'IRQ_10', 'IRQ_11', 'IRQ_12', 
                             'IRQ_13', 'IRQ_14', 'IRQ_15', 'IRQ_16', 'IRQ_17', 'IRQ_18', 
                             'IRQ_19', 'IRQ_20', 'IRQ_21', 'IRQ_22', 'IRQ_23', 'IRQ_24', 
                             'IRQ_25', 'IRQ_26', 'IRQ_27', 'IRQ_28', 'IRQ_29', 'IRQ_30', 'IRQ_31',"IRQ_32",
                             'CEER_1', 'CEER_2', 'CEER_3', 'CEER_4','CEER_5','CEER_6',
                             'CEER_7','CEER_8','CEER_9','CEER_10','CEER_11','CEER_12',
                             'IRIS_1', 'IRIS_2', 'IRIS_3', 'IRIS_4','IRIS_5','IRIS_6',
                             'IRIS_7','IRIS_8','IRIS_9','IRIS_10','IRIS_11','IRIS_12',
                             'IRIS_13', 'IRIS_14', 'IRIS_15', 'IRIS_16', 'IRIS_17', 'IRIS_18', 
                             'IRIS_19', "IRIS_20", "IRIS_21", "IRIS_22", "IRIS_23", "IRIS_24", 
                             'IRIS_25', 'IRIS_26', 'IRIS_27', 'IRIS_28',
                             'DERS_1', 'DERS_2', 'DERS_3', 'DERS_4','DERS_5','DERS_6',
                             'DERS_7','DERS_8','DERS_9','DERS_10','DERS_11','DERS_12',
                             'DERS_13', 'DERS_14', 'DERS_15', 'DERS_16',
                             'CTS2_1_R', 'CTS2_2_R', 'CTS2_3_R', 'CTS2_4_R', 'CTS2_5_R', 'CTS2_6_R', 
                             'CTS2_7_R', 'CTS2_8_R', 'CTS2_9_R', 'CTS2_10_R', 'CTS2_11_R', 'CTS2_12_R', 
                             'CTS2_13_R', 'CTS2_14_R', 'CTS2_15_R', 'CTS2_16_R', 'CTS2_17_R', 'CTS2_18_R', 
                             'CTS2_19_R', 'CTS2_20_R', 'CTS2_21_R', 'CTS2_22_R', 'CTS2_23_R', 'CTS2_24_R', 
                             'CTS2_25_R', 'CTS2_26_R', 'CTS2_27_R', 'CTS2_28_R', 'CTS2_29_R', 'CTS2_30_R', 
                             'CTS2_31_R', 'CTS2_32_R', 'CTS2_33_R', 'CTS2_34_R', 'CTS2_35_R', 'CTS2_36_R', 
                             'CTS2_37_R', 'CTS2_38_R', 'CTS2_39_R', 'CTS2_40_R', 'CTS2_41_R', 'CTS2_42_R', 
                             'CTS2_43_R', 'CTS2_44_R', 'CTS2_45_R', 'CTS2_46_R', 'CTS2_47_R', 'CTS2_48_R', 
                             'CTS2_49_R', 'CTS2_50_R', 'CTS2_51_R', 'CTS2_52_R', 'CTS2_53_R', 'CTS2_54_R',
                             'CARS_1_R','CARS_2_R', 'CARS_3_R', 'CARS_4_R', 'CARS_5_R', 'CARS_6_R', 
                             'CARS_7_R','CARS_8_R', 'CARS_9_R', 'CARS_10_R', 'CARS_11_R', 'CARS_12_R', 
                             'CARS_13_R','CARS_14_R', 'CARS_15_R', 'CARS_16_R','CARS_17_R','CARS_18_R', 
                             'CARS_19_R','CARS_20_R', 'CARS_21_R', 'CARS_22_R', 'CARS_23_R','CARS_24_R', 
                             'CARS_25_R','CARS_26_R', 'CARS_27_R', 'CARS_28_R', 'CARS_29_R','CARS_30_R', 
                             'CARS_31_R','CARS_32_R', 'CARS_33_R', 'CARS_34_R',  
                             'Relation_length_months', 'Relation_status', 'Income',
                             'Current_age', 'Gender', 'Aboriginal', 
                             'Commit_1', 'Commit_2', 'Commit_3','Commit_4', 'Commit_5','Commit_6','Commit_7',                           
                             'AUDIT_1','AUDIT_2', 'AUDIT_3', 'AUDIT_4', 'AUDIT_5', 'AUDIT_6',
                             'AUDIT_7', 'AUDIT_8', 'AUDIT_9',  'AUDIT_10')]

    ## multiple imputation 
       alldata4.mi <- mice::mice(alldata4, m = 5, method = 'pmm')
    
    ## obtain each dataset from the stacked dataset (the first one first)
        ECR.alldata4.mi.1 <- mice::complete(alldata4.mi, c(1))
        ECR.alldata4.mi.2 <- mice::complete(alldata4.mi, c(2))
        ECR.alldata4.mi.3 <- mice::complete(alldata4.mi, c(3))
        ECR.alldata4.mi.4 <- mice::complete(alldata4.mi, c(4))
        ECR.alldata4.mi.5 <- mice::complete(alldata4.mi, c(5))

## total score of ECR - anxiety after multiple imputation for each of the 5 imputed dataset 
ECR.alldata4.mi.1$ECR_anxiety_average_mi <- rowMeans(ECR.alldata4.mi.1[c("ECR_2", "ECR_4", "ECR_6", "ECR_8","ECR_10","ECR_12","ECR_14","ECR_16","ECR_18",
                                                                 "ECR_20","ECR_22","ECR_24","ECR_26","ECR_28","ECR_30","ECR_32","ECR_34","ECR_36")])

## total score of IRQ - original after multiple imputation for each of the 5 imputed dataset 
ECR.alldata4.mi.1$IRQ_original_total_mi <- rowSums(ECR.alldata4.mi.1[c("IRQ_1", "IRQ_3", "IRQ_5", "IRQ_7","IRQ_9","IRQ_11","IRQ_13","IRQ_15","IRQ_17",
                                                               "IRQ_19","IRQ_21","IRQ_23","IRQ_25","IRQ_27","IRQ_29","IRQ_31")])

#### I created the total scores of the variables included in the mediations code. I did not present all of them here to save space.

    # assign variables to their roles for the "mediations" function
    datasets <- list(ECR.alldata4.mi.1=ECR.alldata4.mi.1, ECR.alldata4.mi.2=ECR.alldata4.mi.2, 
                     ECR.alldata4.mi.3=ECR.alldata4.mi.3, 
                     ECR.alldata4.mi.4=ECR.alldata4.mi.4, ECR.alldata4.mi.5=ECR.alldata4.mi.5) # list of multiply imputed data sets
    
    mediators <- c("IRQ_original_total_mi", "IRQ_partner_total_mi", "CEER_total_mi", "IRIS_total_mi", "DERS_total_mi")
    outcome <- c("CTS2_psy_perp_total_mi")
    treatment <- c("ECR_anxiety_average_mi","ECR_anxiety_average_mi","ECR_anxiety_average_mi","ECR_anxiety_average_mi","ECR_anxiety_average_mi")  # note how the treatment indicator is repeated to match the number of datasets
    
    # mediation analysis
    olsols <- mediations(datasets, treatment, mediators, outcome, families=c("gaussian","gaussian"), 
                         interaction=FALSE, conf.level=.90, sims=1000, boot=TRUE)
```

Comment: For those who have similar issues, please see https://github.com/kosukeimai/mediation/issues/32